# How can I process rostopic on a remote pc host?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ssh, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.
My question is, how can I process topic data on a remote pc. I have a robot connected to a local network. I can see the ros topics on the remote pc using SSH. For my application, the ROS master must run on the robot, not the host. I have tried writing a text file inside robot memory and reading it on a remote pc, but this method is slow and does not seem to be correct. Can anyone help me through this? How can I transfer data (Like a simple Integer) to a host in Ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377976/how-can-i-process-rostopic-on-a-remote-pc-host?/) by [navid](https://answers.ros.org/users/45640/navid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, navidzarrabi

run `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:11311` and `export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.XXX.XXX.XXX` on your
robot,`192.XXX.XXX.XXX` is your robot ip address.

run `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:11311` and `export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.YYY.YYY.YYY` on your PC
`192.XXX.XXX.XXX` is your robot ip address, `192.YYY.YYY.YYY` is your PC ip address.

then, you can do most operations on your pc. such as rviz, rqt_gui.

In fact, i think this makes your pc know where is master and makes your robot know where is itself.It works for me, i hope it works for you,too.

---

Originally posted by [IgararA](https://answers.ros.org/users/74208/igarara/) with karma: 36 on 2021-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1